# The benefit of Viewsets in Django rest framework

Tags: django-rest-framework

I was learning Django rest and came across something called Viewsets which confused me a bit. That is, as the docs says "A ViewSet class is simply a type of class-based View, that does not provide any method handlers such as .get() or .post(), and instead provides actions such as .list() and .create().". Ok, viewset serve as abstration over http methods like get() or post(). But, what is the benefit of the viewset providing us with abstraction, I mean, what if we use get() instead of list()?

Comment: If you continue reading that part of the documentation for a few more paragraphs it mostly clears things up, no…?

Comment: Viewsets are an abstraction around resources.

Answer (score 0):

DRF ViewSet will help you to ensure the consistent URL, it will minimize the amount of code that you will usually need to write and another great benefit is ViewSet allows developer to focus on interactions and representation of API instead of URL configuration specifis.